# Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>' to specified type 'NSFetchRequest<T>'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios10

I want to use new Core Data API introduced in iOS10.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
open class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>
```

I created generic function to fetching all kinds of objects:

```
func getAllEntities<T: NSManagedObject>(ofType type: T.Type, success: @escaping ([T]) -> ()) throws -> [T] {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest()
    let asyncFetchRequest = NSAsynchronousFetchResult(fetchRequest: fetchRequest) { result in
        success(result.finalResult ?? [])
    }

    try databaseStack.persistentContainer.viewContext.execute(asyncFetchRequest)
}
```

but in line `let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest()` I got issue:

> Cannot convert value of type `'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>'` to specified type `'NSFetchRequest<T>'`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I have exacly the same problem. The strangest thing is that, I have one project where it's working like a charm, and another one with the error, same as you.
Here: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/cleaning-up-core-data-fetch-requests/ is our solution described.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`T.fetchRequest()` returns a `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>`,
you have to explicitly cast it to the specific `NSFetchRequest<T>`:

```
let fetchRequest = T.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<T>
let asyncFetchRequest = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest) { result in
    success(result.finalResult ?? [])
}
```

Comment: I had hope that I can skip force casting. I demanded from `.fetchRequest()` explicit type. Well, nothing. Tnx for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try either one of these.

**One:**
I experienced something similar in my project.

I found that there were problems with the auto generated headers of Core Data entities. Try deleting from:

`/Users/**user**/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**AppName**/Build/Intermediates/**AppName**/Debug-iphonesimulator/**AppName**.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated`

then clean your project with
`command+shift+K`

Then try building.

**Two:**
Try using `let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: NSStringFromClass(T.self))`

**Swifty** style of 2nd approach, works 100%:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: String(describing: T.self))
```

Comment: I set in my data model `Codegen` as `Manual/None` so I don't have autogenerated code. Maybe is causes the problem?

Comment: Updated my answer again

Comment: Second proposition is a workaround. I want to find why my solution doesn't work without using different API.

Answer (score 0):

The NSFetchRequest `boilerplate` call (for array of information, for instance) ends with `()`; don't forget that or you might get an error of this type.

This is easy to miss especially if you type your code out instead of copy-pasting the boiler-plate code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this extension for ManagedObject, I've force unwrap `entity.name` and allowed it to crash if return `nil`.

```
    public static func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Self> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Self>(entityName: Self.entityName)
    }
    
    public static var entity: NSEntityDescription { return entity()  }
    
    /// - important: If name return nil, check xcmodeld and Module config Current Product Module
    public static var entityName: String { return entity.name!  }
```